# How to make an aggregated line chart in klipfolio

Tags: klipfolio

Trying to make an aggregated line chart based on some signups, but the issue is that the dataset I have (json), only gives me a value for each day, and not the aggregated (a number that increments each day).

Does anyone have an idea what function or setting i need to use?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to accumulating and aggregating the daily values? IE. the value for yesterday = 1 and the value for today  = 2 so the value of today in the series is 3?

If so, you can use the [CUMULATIVE()](https://support.klipfolio.com/hc/en-us/articles/215547888-CUMULATIVE-function) function in your series:

```
CUMULATIVE(@/number)
```

This will cumulatively add your daily data in your JSON data source from the first record to the last.